# How to export 3DS files from Maya?

Tags: 3d-modeling, maya

How can I export a mesh and textures to 3DS format from Maya 2011?

Comment: What are you trying to import it into after Maya that needs 3ds, Max?

Comment: I'd like to use the mesh in a realtime renderer that supports 3DS.  3DS seems like a simple enough lowest-common-denominator format.

Answer (score 1):

What I normaly do is export it as an FBX then import it into Daz Studio (which can turn it into a 3ds if need be). The Daz fbx plugin is around 100 usd if you're not a platinum club member though.